# Will other players see my Pokémon's nickname if I put it into a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say that I nickname my Pokémon "Arqade" and place it in a gym. Will other players see that nickname? Or will they just see the default name for the Pokémon?

I've seen a picture of "[Merica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQH3m.jpg)", a Pigeotto that at one point held the gym at the White House, so I'm inclined to think yes. But at my local gyms, I've never seen a nicknamed Pokémon, which makes me wonder if only the original trainer sees it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot see other people's Pokemon nicknames at gyms. The only reason you can see the nicknames in pictures is because it is their pokemon. As stated in the link below, the pokemon nickname can only be seen by **you**.

> 4. Touch to create a personal nickname that can only be seen by you

[image]

[Source](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049867-Viewing-a-Pok%C3%A9mon-s-Summary-)

Comment: For any new players viewing the picture and noticing discrepancies, this is because Niantic got rid of the location feature as well as moved the transfer button.

Comment: @Riftcaster: If the answer is true and the nickname is indeed only visible to you, the Pokemon's owner, then that screenshot was taken by the player Saigun himself.

Comment: @Riftcaster He simply found the picture the trainer had posted online and retweeted it. How does that not explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously seen other people's Pokemon's nicknames since I started playing, but have not seen them for some time now, which makes me believe it was possible earlier, but was patched out on either servers or game client or both and it's not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the nicknames of mons only when they have it as a buddy and are friends with you to exchange gifts or trade. Other than that you will not see any nicknames at gyms nor will they see yours.